# In learning theory, why can't we bound like $P[|E_{in}(g)-E_{out}(g)|>\epsilon] \leq 2e^{-2\epsilon^{2}N}$?($g$ is our learned hypothesis)

Tags: machine-learning, bounds

Given Data $D_{in}$, number of data $N=|D_{in}|$, and hypothesis set $H=\{h_1,h_2, ...,h_M\}$.

For a fixed hypothesis $h$, for example $h_1$, we can derive

$$P[|E_{in}(h_1)-E_{out}(h_1)|>\epsilon] \leq 2e^{-2\epsilon^{2}N}$$

from hoeffding's inequality since $\mathbb{E}_{D_{in}}[E_{in}(h_1)]=E_{out}(h_1)$.

If $g$ is our learned hypothesis using the data $D_{in}$, we can't apply hoeffding's inequality directly since $\mathbb{E}_{D_{in}}[E_{in}(g)] \neq E_{out}(g)$.

But my question is, why can't we bound $P[|E_{in}(g)-E_{out}(g)|>\epsilon]$ as following:

$
P[|E_{in}(g)-E_{out}(g)|>\epsilon] \\\
= \sum_{h \in H} P[|E_{in}(g)-E_{out}(g)|>\epsilon  \;\land \;g=h]\\\
= \sum_{h \in H} P[|E_{in}(g)-E_{out}(g)|>\epsilon \;\lvert \;g=h]\;P[g=h] \\\
= \sum_{h \in H} P[|E_{in}(h)-E_{out}(h)|>\epsilon]\;P[g=h] \\\
\leq \sum_{h \in H} (2e^{-2\epsilon^{2}N})\;P[g=h] \\\
= 2e^{-2\epsilon^{2}N}$

Inequality $P[|E_{in}(g)-E_{out}(g)|>\epsilon] \leq 2e^{-2\epsilon^{2}N}$ means that for the probability $1-\delta$, and learned hypothesis $g$ using $D_{in}$, inequality
$$E_{out}(g) \leq E_{in}(g) + \sqrt{{1 \over 2N}ln{2\over\delta}}$$

holds and thus, the size of hypothesis set $|H|$ doesn't affect generalization bound.

Is this wrong? Where am I doing wrong?

If this inequality is right, why do we use uniform convergence bound like: 
$$
\forall g \in H, \;P[|E_{in}(g)-E_{out}(g)|>\epsilon] \leq 2|H|e^{-2\epsilon^{2}N}
$$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the error is in the following equality

$$\sum_{h \in H} P[|E_{in}(g)-E_{out}(g)|>\epsilon \;\lvert \;g=h]\;P[g=h]
= \sum_{h \in H} P[|E_{in}(h)-E_{out}(h)|>\epsilon]\;P[g=h]$$

but its hidden by the notation.

Consider your equality

$$ P [|E_{in}(g)-E_{out}(g)|>\epsilon \;\lvert \;g=h] = P [|E_{in}(h)-E_{out}(h)|>\epsilon] $$

It is only *specific* training sets $X, Y$ that produce $g = h$.  And, unfortunately, it is exactly these data sets that bias the out of sample error to be higher than the training error. To produce an equality like this you have to *change the probability space* to include only those training data sets for which $g = h$, so $P$ just doesn't mean the same thing on the left and the right hand sides.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I recognized the error you mentioned. Thank you. I have a few more questions. Is there any way to bound $P [|E_{in}(g)-E_{out}(g)|>\epsilon \;\lvert \;g=h]$ value which finally leads to $P[|E_{in}(g)-E_{out}(g)|>\epsilon] \leq 2|H|e^{-2\epsilon^{2}N}$?

Comment: Also, I'm having a trouble with 'How to connect inequality $\forall h \in H, \;P[|E_{in}(h)-E_{out}(h)|>\epsilon] \leq 2|H|e^{-2\epsilon^{2}N}$ to inequality $P[|E_{in}(g)-E_{out}(g)|>\epsilon] \leq 2|H|e^{-2\epsilon^{2}N}$ if $g$ is our learned hypothesis'. I understood it intuitively, but I'm having trouble with formulating rigorous mathematical equations.

Comment: For your second question, you simply must observe that $g \in H$, so it is being quantified over in the $\forall$.  For the first, I can't say for sure, but since you don't have much control over the conditional probability space, i'd be surprised if it was easy to do so.

Comment: Thanks! I finally understood. Thank you. However, I have one more last question. Could you please give me an explanation about my another question? http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/157967/in-statistical-learning-theory-isnt-there-a-problem-of-overfitting-on-a-test-s